# Why aren't norms used in the definition of Finsler manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, definition, examples-counterexamples, finsler-geometry

In the definition of Finsler manifolds, each tangent space is endowed with an [asymmetric norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_norm), which is more general than a norm. (I think Spivak calls them "Minkowski metrics" in [Volume 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098713).)

**Question:** What is the reason for this generality? What are some important examples of Finsler manifolds where the tangent spaces have asymmetric norms which aren't also norms?

Comment: I think of special relativity when I hear "Minkowski metric", which does not use an asymmetric norm. Differential geometry might have different conventions than physics, though.

Comment: @Arthur I definitely agree with you. I have used "Minkowski" used to refer to at least three separate things: (1) non-positive-definite bilinear forms, (2)  $p$-norms, (3) and the asymmetric norm thing. At this point I have no idea what Minkowski actually studied.

Comment: Non-standard norms in general, perhaps?